# Pandas Dataframe to_dict() with unique column values as keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['jars', 'used'], 'B': ['Phrase', 'Phrase']})

      A       B
0  jars  Phrase
1  used  Phrase
```

Desired Output:

```
{'Phrase': ['jars', 'used']}
```

If column `B` has multiple unique values (say: Unique values were `Broad`, `Phrase` and `Exact`):

```
{'Phrase': ['jars', 'used'], 'Exact': ['val1', 'val2'], 'Broad': ['cat', 'dog']}
```

I was thinking something like this but `A` is the key.

```
df.set_index('B').to_dict('list')

{'A': ['jars', 'used']}
```

I've tried:

```
>>> dict([(b,[a]) for b, a in zip(df.B, df.A)])
{'Phrase': ['used']}

>>> [{b:[a]} for b, a in zip(df.B, df.A)]
[{'Phrase': ['jars']}, {'Phrase': ['used']}]

>>> df.set_index('B').T.to_dict('list')
{'Phrase': ['used']}
```

This is probably stupid-simple.

Comment: What about if `df.B` had multiple unique values?

Comment: Then `{'Phrase': ['jars', 'used'], 'Exact': ['val1', 'val2'], 'Broad': ['cat', 'dog']}`.  In my real dataset, column `B` does have multiple unique values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [11]: df.groupby('B').agg({'A': lambda x: x.tolist()})['A'].to_dict()
Out[11]: {'Phrase': ['jars', 'used']}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['jars', 'used', 'fun', 'what', 'when'],
           'B': ['Phrase', 'Phrase', 'Exact', 'Exact', 'Broad']},
          columns=['A', 'B'])
df
      A       B
0  jars  Phrase
1  used  Phrase
2   fun   Exact
3  what   Exact
4  when   Broad
```

Another way using `apply` instead of `agg`:

```
df.groupby('B').apply(lambda f: f['A'].values.tolist()).to_dict()
```

Returns:

```
{'Broad': ['when'], 'Exact': ['fun', 'what'], 'Phrase': ['jars', 'used']}
```